# The meaning of random and gain in cost/benefit analysis in weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

[image]

This is cost sensitive analysis in Weka.

What's the meaning of Random and Gain?

In which class file can I find the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Random is the cost of a random classifier.

Gain is the difference, how much better your classifier is than the random classifier.

The most interesting value would be gain/random: how much you improved over the random classifier in relative terms.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! What's the meaning of a random classifier? ZeroR? And do you know source code of this part in which class file or pakage in weka? Thank you again! ^_^